# Spring MVC and Hibernate: NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception NoClassDefFoundError:JsonMappingException$Reference

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

- am trying to integration Spring MVC and Hibernate & Oracle 11g
- tables are Users & Org & UserOrg[forgin Keys userId,orgId]
- pom.xml

  ```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tests</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>tests Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
      <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
      <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
      <mysql.version>5.1.10</mysql.version>
      <junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
      <servlet-api-version>3.1.0</servlet-api-version>
      <jsp-version>2.1</jsp-version>
      <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Hibernate 4 dependencies -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
          <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Servlet and JSP -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
          <version>${jsp-version}</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- JSTL dependency -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>jstl</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>${jstl-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- JUnit -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>${junit-version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- External oralce jar -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>ojdbc7</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Json dependency -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Json dependency -->
      <!-- slf4j-log4j -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.1</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
      <finalName>tests</finalName>
      <!-- <resources> <resource> <directory>src/main/java</directory> <includes> 
          <include>**/*.xml</include> <include>**/*.properties</include> </includes> 
          </resource> </resources> -->
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>D:\Newfolder\Softwares\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments</outputDirectory>                       
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                  <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
  ```
- Entity Files
- Org.java & Users.java & UsersOrg.java

  ```
      package com.tests.entity;
  /**
   * Org generated by hbm2java
   */
  @Entity
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "orgId")
  public class Org implements java.io.Serializable {
      @Id
      @Column(name = "orgId")
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private BigDecimal orgId;
      private BigDecimal parentOrgId;
      private BigDecimal orgCode;
      private String orgName;
      private String description;
      private BigDecimal actStat;
      private Set<UserOrg> userOrgs = new HashSet<UserOrg>(0);        
      public Org() {
      }
      public Org(BigDecimal orgId, BigDecimal parentOrgId, BigDecimal orgCode, String orgName, BigDecimal actStat) {
          this.orgId = orgId;
          this.parentOrgId = parentOrgId;
          this.orgCode = orgCode;
          this.orgName = orgName;
          this.actStat = actStat;
      }
      public Org(BigDecimal orgId, BigDecimal parentOrgId, BigDecimal orgCode, String orgName, String description, BigDecimal actStat,
               Set<UserOrg> userOrgs) {
          this.orgId = orgId;
          this.parentOrgId = parentOrgId;
          this.orgCode = orgCode;
          this.orgName = orgName;
          this.description = description;
          this.actStat = actStat;
          this.userOrgs = userOrgs;
      }
      public BigDecimal getOrgId() {
          return this.orgId;
      }
      public void setOrgId(BigDecimal orgId) {
          this.orgId = orgId;
      }
      public BigDecimal getParentOrgId() {
          return this.parentOrgId;
      }
      public void setParentOrgId(BigDecimal parentOrgId) {
          this.parentOrgId = parentOrgId;
      }
      public BigDecimal getOrgCode() {
          return this.orgCode;
      }
      public void setOrgCode(BigDecimal orgCode) {
          this.orgCode = orgCode;
      }
      public String getOrgName() {
          return this.orgName;
      }
      public void setOrgName(String orgName) {
          this.orgName = orgName;
      }
      public String getDescription() {
          return this.description;
      }
      public void setDescription(String description) {
          this.description = description;
      }
      public BigDecimal getActStat() {
          return this.actStat;
      }
      public void setActStat(BigDecimal actStat) {
          this.actStat = actStat;
      }
      public BigDecimal getOrgPhone() {
          return this.orgPhone;
      }
      @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
      // @JsonIgnore
      public Set<UserOrg> getUserOrgs() {
          return this.userOrgs;
      }
      // @ManyToOne(cascade={}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      // @JsonIgnore
      public void setUserOrgs(Set<UserOrg> userOrgs) {
          this.userOrgs = userOrgs;
      }
  }
  ```
- same as Users.java & UserOrg.java[orgId,userId forgin keys]
- hibernate hbm xml files Users.hbm.xml & UserOrg.hbm.xml & Org.hbm.xml

  ```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
  <!-- Generated Jun 17, 2016 3:32:52 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
  <hibernate-mapping package="com.tests.entity">
      <class name="Org" table="ORG">
      <id name="orgId" type="big_decimal">
          <column name="ORG_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="parentOrgId" type="big_decimal">
          <column name="PARENT_ORG_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
      </property>
      <property name="orgCode" type="big_decimal">
          <column name="ORG_CODE" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
      </property>
      <property name="orgName" type="string">
          <column name="ORG_NAME" length="32" not-null="true" unique="true" />
      </property>
      <property name="description" type="string">
          <column name="DESCRIPTION" length="100" />
      </property>
      <property name="actStat" type="big_decimal">
          <column name="ACT_STAT" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
      </property>        
      <set name="userOrgs" table="USER_ORG" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
          <key>
          <column name="ORG_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
          </key>
          <one-to-many class="UserOrg" />
      </set>
      <set name="branches" table="BRANCH" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
          <key>
          <column name="ORG_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
          </key>
          <one-to-many class="Branch" />
      </set>
      <!-- <set name="users" table="USER_ORG" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select"> 
          <key>
          <column name="ORG_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
          </key>
          <many-to-many class="Users" column="USER_ID" />
      </set>
      <set name="branches" table="BRANCH" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
          <key>
          <column name="ORG_ID" precision="22" scale="0" not-null="true" />
          </key>
          <one-to-many class="Branch" />
      </set> -->
      </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
  ```
- UserOrg.hbm.xml

  ```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
  <!-- Generated Jun 17, 2016 3:32:52 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
  <hibernate-mapping package="com.tests.entity">
      <class name="UserOrg" table="USER_ORG">
      <id name="userOrgId" type="big_decimal">
          <column name="USER_ORG_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
          <generator class="assigned" />
      </id>
      <many-to-one name="org" class="Org"  fetch="select">
          <column name="ORG_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
      </many-to-one>
      <many-to-one name="users" class="Users" fetch="select">
          <column name="USER_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
      </many-to-one>
      </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
  ```
- Hibernate Util file

  ```
      package com.tests.util;
  @Repository
  public class HibernateUtil {
      @Autowired
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
      public Object getByUserId(String userQuery, String userId) {

          return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(userQuery).setParameter("userId", userId).uniqueResult();
      }
  }
  ```
- Interceptor class

  ```
      package com.tests.interceptor;
  public class OrganizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
      @Override
      public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
          String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
          if (servletPath.equals("/organization")) {
              return true;
          }
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```
- and Other Service & Dao classes
- Controller Class

  ```
      package com.tests.controller;


  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("organization")
  public class OrganizationLoginController {
      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
      private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrganizationLoginController.class);
      @Autowired
      private OrganizationService organizationService;
      @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "rawtypes" })
      @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "", "login" })
      public @ResponseBody void organizationLogin(@RequestParam(required = false) String userName, @RequestParam(required = false) String password,
              HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
              Users loginUser = organizationService.getLoginAuthentication(userName, password);
              if(loginUser != null){
                  //Do something
              }else{              
                  //Do something
              }
      }
  }
  ```
- deployment project but when run the application i got error [error log is below]
- i have done many changes but getting same error, If @JsonIgnore using then its working fine but am unable to get mapping data.
- Server.log

  ```
      15:32:36,948 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ajp-localhost-127.0.0.1-8009-1) Could not complete request: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException$Reference
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1287) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
      at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
      at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:505) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
      at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:445) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonMappingException$Reference
      at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:166) [jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
      at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112) [jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:1.9.13]
  ```
- please help me where i did wrong, am new in hibernat
- thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding jackson-core-asl dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @KLajdpaja for replay, i have added but still getting same error.

Comment: This line seems odd to me: `private Set<UserOrg> userOrgs = new HashSet<UserOrg>(0);`.I would have done `private Set<UserOrg> userOrgs;` to let initialization in hibernate hands